# How to fix the "this.$refs.[ref_name].save is not a function" in a "v-for" created component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a table list with some crud actions. When I click on the edit icon, I will open a dialog box that includes 3 "v-tabs-items" through a **"v-for"**.

In the last v-tab i have an **v-time-picker** input in a menu, and use the structure of the Vuetify documentation.

```
<template>
<v-flex>
  <v-data-table>
    <!-- some data -->
  </v-data-table>
  <v-dialog
    v-model="dialog"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-flex>
        <v-toolbar color="secondary" light tabs>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-spacer />

          <template v-slot:extension>
            <v-tabs
              v-model="tab"
              color="secondary"
              align-with-title
            >
              <v-tabs-slider color="accent" />
              <v-tab v-for="i in items" :key="i">
                {{ i }}
              </v-tab>
            </v-tabs>
          </template>
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
          <v-tab-item v-for="i in items" :key="i">
            <v-card flat>
              <v-card-text v-if="i === 'Ad'" class="pa-0">
                <!-- Some Content -->
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-text v-if="i === 'Content'" class="pa-0">
                <!-- Some Content -->
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-text v-if="i === 'Target'" class="pa-0">
                <v-container grid-list-md>
                  <v-layout wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm6 md6>
                      <v-menu
                        ref="time_picker"
                        v-model="dailyTimeMenu1"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        :nudge-right="-15"
                        :return-value.sync="editedItem.daily_time_from"
                        lazy
                        transition="scale-transition"
                        offset-y
                        full-width
                        max-width="290px"
                        min-width="290px"
                      >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="editedItem.daily_time_from"
                            label="Time From"
                            prepend-icon="access_time"
                            readonly
                            outline
                            class="mr-2"
                            v-on="on"
                          />
                        </template>
                        <v-time-picker
                          v-if="dailyTimeMenu1"
                          v-model="editedItem.daily_time_from"
                          full-width
                          @click:minute="$refs.time_picker.save(editedItem.daily_time_from)"
                        />
                      </v-menu>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm6 md6>
                      <v-menu
                        ref="time_picker"
                        v-model="dailyTimeMenu2"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        :nudge-right="-15"
                        :return-value.sync="editedItem.daily_time_to"
                        lazy
                        transition="scale-transition"
                        offset-y
                        full-width
                        disabled
                        max-width="290px"
                        min-width="290px"
                      >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="editedItem.daily_time_to"
                            label="Time to"
                            prepend-icon="access_time"
                            readonly
                            outline
                            v-on="on"
                          />
                        </template>
                        <v-time-picker
                          v-if="dailyTimeMenu2"
                          v-model="editedItem.daily_time_to"
                          full-width
                          @click:minute="$refs.time_picker.save(editedItem.daily_time_to)
                        />
                      </v-menu>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-container>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer />
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close">
                  Cancel
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="saved">
                  Save
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
      </v-flex>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</v-flex></template>
```

...
and the script and Data object is.

```
<script>
export default {
  data: vm => ({
    dailyTimeMenu1: false,
    dailyTimeMenu2: false,
    items: [
      'Ad', 'Content', 'Target'
    ],
    tab: null,
    dialog: false,
    editedItem: {
      daily_time_from: null,
      daily_time_to: null,
    }
  })
}
```

The problem happens when I want to save the time when I pick the minutes.
I receive this error:

**this.$refs.time_picker.save is not a function**

Can you please explain to me what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: The Vuetify `v-menu` component doesn't appear to expose a `save()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `ref="time_picker"` in a `v-for`, `this.$refs.time_picker` will actually be an array. So you will need to keep track of the index in

```
<v-tab-item v-for="(i, idx) in items" :key="i">
```

and use `idx` in your all of your references to `$refs.time_picker`, like:

```
@click:minute="$refs.time_picker[idx].save(editedItem.daily_time_to)
```

**EDIT**: You also need to rename the second v-menu with the ref `time_picker` to something else, as it is now ambiguous which element you are referring to.

Comment: Actually, the OP is also using `ref="time_picker"` on the `<v-menu />` component, so this won't work either

Comment: Hi, this still doesn't work in the code. I still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks friends for the assistance. it worked when i used the 0 index. i.e.
``` javascript
$refs.time_picker[0]
```
@click:minute="$refs.time_picker[idx].save(editedItem.daily_time_to)
```
in here and instead of 
```